Custom-shaped and borderless window in Avalonia UI
I need to make a custom window in Avalonia UI, free of any OS decorations (Windows 11 in this case). So far I was able to find a bunch of properties that made the window completely transparent, but the border and the shadow won't go away.
So, how can I leave just the green circle and get rid of the rectangular border and its shadow?

Here's copyable XAML for convenience.
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="avava.MainWindow"
        Width="200"
        Height="200"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Background="Transparent"
        TransparencyBackgroundFallback="Transparent"
        ExtendClientAreaToDecorationsHint="True"
        ExtendClientAreaChromeHints="NoChrome"
        ExtendClientAreaTitleBarHeightHint="-1"
        SystemDecorations="None"
        BorderBrush="Transparent"
        BorderThickness="0">
    <Ellipse Fill="Green" Opacity="0.5" Width="150" Height="150" StrokeThickness="10" Stroke="Blue"/>
</Window>


I also had this iusse and just use a normal usercontrol at end. what i overlay like an dialog. the questions would be why it needs to be an window

I was trying to make a similar "transparent" window to experiment with Avalonia.
After a few hours of digging, I found that...
ExtendClientAreaToDecorationsHint="True"

...seemed to be the culprit in my case.
Try to set the value to "False" - the border and shadows should disappear.
